# Which is better design: Determining if a function should execute from outside of it, or inside of it?

Tags: design

I'm often presented with these two options.  From a design point of view, which of these is subjectively better, and why?

Option A

```
class foo {
  private boolean bar() {
    //Stuff
  }

  private void A() {
     if(bar())
       B();
  }

  private void B() {
      // more stuff
  }
}
```

Option B

```
class foo {
  private boolean bar() {
    //Stuff
  }

  private void A() {
      B();
  }

  private void B() {
     if(!bar())
        return;

     // more stuff
  }
}
```

Let's assume that code duplication isn't an issue here, and the division is only to separate, logically, the code for better readability/understanding (A, B, and bar have meaningful names in context).    Is it more readable to have the reader know that B might not do anything when looking at just A?  Or is the encapsulation of state better put into B?  Obviously, this can be refactored to separate B and bar() into a separate class entirely, which separates concerns even more, but assuming mostly shared state, which is better?

Comment: You'll get more useful responses if you accept that either might be right in some circumstances, and ask for examples of appropriate circumstances

Comment: In Option B, method A is totally pointless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The important bit is *who owns bar*? If it's unclear, consider if B can live up to it's method name considering the value of Bar. If so, then make it part of B. If not, then make it part of A.

In a real world scenario, you'll generally find methods that fulfill a design responsibility, and helper methods that fulfill implementation steps. Generally, the decision of whether to call an implementation method resides with the API method - which is *generally* the public method.

```
public class Control {
    public bool IsVisible;
    public void Render() {
       if (this.IsVisible) {
          this.PrepareForRender();
       }
    }
    private void PrepareForRender() {
       // just do it. Don't check IsVisible
    }
 }
```

It's possible that you have two different API methods calling each other. In that case, I'd suggest falling back on the semantics of why doesn't B run when Bar is false? Is it because B is unnecessary - then B should decide.

```
 public class List {
    public int Count;
    public void SetTo(object[] values) {
       this.Clear(); // need to clear values; don't really care how
    }
    public void Clear() {
       // Count = 0 is just a shortcut to fulfilling Clear's responsibility
       if (this.Count == 0) return; 
    }
 }
```

Is it because B is incorrect? Then A should decide.

```
public class File {
    public bool IsBinary;
    public void Write() {
       if (this.IsBinary) {
          this.OpenBinaryStream();
       } else {
          this.OpenTextStream();
       }     
    }
    private void OpenBinaryStream() {
    }
    private void OpenTextStream() {
    }
 }
```

Because it's actively harmful? A should decide, and B should throw an exception:

```
public class File {
    public bool UseSecureDelete;
    public void Delete() {
       if (this.UseSecureDelete) {
          this.ZeroBytes();
       }
    }
    private void ZeroBytes() {
       if (!this.UseSecureDelete) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

I strongly disagree with @jmquigley.

Whatever "performance gain" is in-play here is minuscule and negligible.

The "if" condition should reside in the member in which it's logically (or even semantically) a part of.

Since you haven't clued us in to what the actual object or member functions are, only you can make this decision.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit, which I hope helps.  In short, my question is exactly what you state, what helps determine the logical place?  Is 'possibly not executing' a concern of the caller or the called?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether `foo()` and `B()` lie on the same level of abstraction.

If they do, then *Option A* is preferable.

Otherwise (`foo()` is an implementation detail of `B()` and therefore lower than `B()`) *Option B* is better.

So, the guiding principle here is: *don't mix levels of abstraction*.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest code wins.  You don't want to have multiple appearances of:

```
 if(!bar.contains(baz))
   B(baz, stuff);
```

If you NEVER want to add something to bar that is already present, the second implementation is clearly superior.

However, in almost all modern languages, you could make `bar` a set, and then say something like this:

```
if (bar.add(baz))
  // more stuff
```

Comment: +1 good point.  I was looking at it a different way, but I like your analysis (I should have been thinking DRY).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've clarified the question a bit.  Duplication isn't an issue, this is an isolated algorithm that's divided only for readability, not re-use, yet.  However, I agree a re-use scenario might force the decision one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consult with the mythical rubber duck of the ["Rubber duck debugging"](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) fame. Don't be fooled by his debugging powers because he is also adept at figuring out design issues.

Comment: I asked the design Teddy Bear, and he was stumped too, but thanks for the suggestion!